# How to connect mysql with jcreator?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jcreator

I am using jceator 4.50.010 & mysql 5.5.28. my windows version is 7 64 bit.the i installed mysql-connector-odbc-5.2.2-winx64 to connect jcreator with mysql.than i followed the following procedure

```
1. First went to my control panel then Administrative Tools > Data Sources(ODBC)
2. The ODBC Data Source Dialog will then appear, select the System DSN tab.
3. Click on the Add button then another Dialog Box containing the Drivers will appear. Select mysql ODBC Driver then click Finish.
```

Than the window showed which want the following things.

```
1.Data source name
2.User
3.password
4.database
```

I don't know what will be these.the password may be that which i given during installing mysql.When i press the test button it appears the following message

```
"Connection failed:[HY000][mysql][odbc 5.2 w driver] access denied for 'odbc' @ 'localhost' (using password:YES)"
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

why not use the JDBC driver instead ? thats the standard java interface to relational databases
[MySQL/J](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). you have examples in the downloadable package itself.

If you MUST use the ODBC driver, you probably should get a ODBC-JDBC bridge too.

EDIT: 
i believe you are trying to connect to databases in a java application and using jcreator as an IDE. 
you can get the latest jdbc drivers for MySQL in the link i have provided above. a jdbc driver is basically a jar file that you need to have in your classpath like any other library.
Here is a quickstart tutorial 
http://www.vogella.com/articles/MySQLJava/article.html

This is not related or specific to jcreator

As far as jcreator is concerned i havent used it lately myself. i looked at the feature set and dont think you can connect to a database through it. May be you are comparing it with Visual studio which is a all-in-one package where you can do database development (firing SQL queries, looking at the schema ...), i dont think it does that. if you are looking for such features look at [SQL Workbench/J](http://www.sql-workbench.net/) or [DBeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/). these are separate application that let you do database development(ONLY) and have built-in support for mysql.

Comment: where i will get jdbc driver and how i will connect jcreator & mysql through it.Please help me in details

Comment: Sure man.But actually i am not able to find jdbc driver for windows "64 bit".It will be very helpful if you find it for me.Please......

Comment: did you try those ? jdbc drivers are not platform specific, you should be fine with the ones available there.  i am using the same jars on win 7 64 bit.

Comment: Sorry for being late.At last i got it.I connected mysql with netbeans. Thanx a lot. Your help mean a lot to me.